# Starting Django's runserver in a Docker container through docker-compose

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I would like to have Django's **runserver** command running when I call `docker-compose up`

Here is what I tried, firstly, my image is starting from a **Python image** customized following this **dockerfile**:

```sh
# Dockerfile

FROM python:3.8
MAINTAINER geoffroy

# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Ports exposure
EXPOSE 8000
VOLUME /data

# Install dependancies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    vim \
    git \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Setup python dependancies
RUN git clone https://github.com/blondelg/auto.git
WORKDIR /auto
RUN cd /auto
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Build the secret key generator
RUN echo "import random" > generate_key.py
RUN echo "print(''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!@$^&*(-_=+)') for i in range(50)))" >> generate_key.py

# Setup environment configuration
RUN cp auto/config_sample.ini auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/SECRET_KEY_PATTERN/$(python generate_key.py)/gI" auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/django.db.backends.sqlite3/django.db.backends.mysql/gI" auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i 's|{BASE_DIR}/db.sqlite3|autodb|gI' auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/USER_PATTERN/root/gI" auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/PASSWORD_PATTERN/root/gI" auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/HOST_PATTERN/database/gI" auto/config.ini
RUN sed -i "s/PORT_PATTERN/3306/gI" auto/config.ini
```

Then, I have my **docker-compose.yml** designed as follow:

```sh
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
    database:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: database
        ports: 
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=autodb
        hostname: 'database'
    runserver:
        build: .
        command: python /auto/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 
        container_name: runserver
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
            - database
```

Then I run

```sh
docker-compose up --build -d
```

My two containers (runserver + database) are up but going to http://127.0.0.1:8000 returns an error page whereas I should have **the Django start page**.

Also, when I go into the container (`docker exec -ti runserver bash`) and when I run `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`, I can access to **the Django start page** through http://127.0.0.1:8000.

What could be wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get from django?  Can you provide the full traceback?

Comment: I get no error. When I put a wrong command in docker-compose.yml (mannage.py for instance),  the runserver container exits when I run ```docker-compose up -d```

Comment: What happens when you visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000` when the container is running?

Comment: @ElrondSupportsMonica, I get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/, Ifixed the way I was declaring volume in my **docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
        volumes:
            - .:/auto
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, there is this line `WORKDIR /auto`. It means that you are already in the `/auto` folder. So, in your docker-compose file, you should say

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Instead of `/auto/manage.py`.

Comment: (This should probably be the image's `CMD`; you shouldn't need to provide an override in the `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: I get the same behavior with ```python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000```

Comment: @DavidMaze, in both cases (CMD from dockerfile or command from docker-compose.yml) I get the same behavior too